# How to run shell scripts of python libraries in AWS lambda?

Tags: python, bash, shell, aws-lambda

I'm able to import the needed python library in my lambda code. However I also want to access the CLI provided by this library. The CLI is launched by file usr/bin/ocrmypdf which is actually a shell script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import sys
from ocrmypdf.__main__ import run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run())
```

I tried adding this file to my lambda layer in /bin/ folder. I'm get this error:

```
File "/opt/bin/ocrmypdf", line 4, in <module>
from ocrmypdf.__main__ import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ocrmypdf'
```

I suspect that the script is not able to load python. The handler code below is producing the CLI's output

```py
import ocrmypdf # works properly
from ocrmypdf.__main__ import run
import logging
import os
print('Loading function')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    run() # this is called by the shell script, it works here
    logging.info(os.system("ocrmypdf --help")) # error
```

Comment: I think you should put your .py file under local/bin/ and call it with CLI using python.

Comment: You mean adding the python code from the shell script to a .py file in /bin/ and calling it from handler?